# HTTP GET Request Formatted Incorrectly

Tags: c, sockets, http, networking, request

I've been pulling my hair out for a while and have found no help. So I have the following GET HTTP Request (being sent through socket):

```
GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n
```

I keep getting an `HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request` response. What does this mean? Am I formatting the request incorrectly somehow?

Comment: Seems ok, the "problem" is probably on the server side. It may not even be a problem at all, if it is some kind of API this request may not be valid. Under the premise that the %s are filled with sane values of course. Maybe you can provide what you really send? (i.e. print it to stdout instead of sending it to the socket)

Comment: `%s` isn't valid. Are you intending to substitute that with something?  If so, you haven't.

Comment: @EJP In this sense, \r\n isn't valid either ;) I assumed that this is the format string in an fprintf or similar.

Comment: Post the actual code, we cannot guess how you are using this format string.